# Hangfire package in MVC on local IIS server responds with "The website declined to show this webpage"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, hangfire

An MVC site is on a local 2016 server using IIS.  The MVC site runs without problem.  But there is a dashboard page generated by the hangfire nuget package that throws the error in the title of this post.

I think I understand the issue.  This page isn't generated by the asp.net code that comprises the MVC website and IIS doesn't want to show that page.

What change is the appropriate way to enable the dashboard page generated by the added hangfire dlls so that IIS will allow it to be displayed?

Added per request in comments:

```
Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        ConfigureAuth(app)

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDbConnection")
        app.UseHangfireDashboard()
        app.UseHangfireServer()
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Sub() HangfireSvrController.AppTimer(), Cron.Minutely)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific HTTP status code for the page? Where is your Hangfire dashboard configuration code?

Comment: HTTP 403.  As a result of your question, I rechecked the hangfire site and there seems to be some information there about this problem.  Reading right now, but if you have an simple explanation that would be great.

Comment: I think that dashboard only works from localhost by default.